# Is it possible to install Windows 10 on VHD with WIMBoot enabled?

Tags: vhd, windows-10-preview

I want to install the Windows 10 preview in my machine. I used preview versions of Windows 8, which was installed in VHD. But in my new machine, the SSD storage is limited. I cannot afford a ~20GB VHD to install Windows 10 preview. I learned about WIMBoot introduced in Windows 8.1, which reduces installation size of Windows on SSD. Now I wonder, whether I can install Windows 10 preview on a VHD with WIMBoot enabled. I can afford 5-7GB of storage for this. Is this possible?

Comment: try it out and let us know if it works or not.

Comment: Windows 10 is Windows 8.1 with a few minor changes really. I would be surprised if it didn't work the same as it did with Windows 8